# How to do localization of error message in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to localize the error message which we are written in our controller.

I am using angular-translate for doing localization, which is working fine for my html pages by using `{{'lt_edit'|translate}}`.

But same thing is not working in my controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got my answer. We need to use filter directive in controller.Something like this.
$scope.failureMsg = $filter('translate')('lt_login-error');